# Array objects added to subview not appearing (swift 3)

Tags: ios, arrays, uiview

I seem to have a problem adding multiple objects of the same array to a subview. I tried making both an array of UIViews and UILabels and got the same result

I made an array of UILabels using the following code (I have a separate func for labels that I called):

```
var labelArray = [UILabel()]
    labelArray.append(label(text: "testing", colour: UIColor.white, lines: 1))
    labelArray.append(label(text: "1, 2, 3", colour: UIColor.white, lines: 1))
```

I then added it to the subview and added constraints to it (i use an extension to shorten the NSLayoutConstraints):

```
    view.addSubview(labelArray[0])
    view.addSubview(labelArray[1])

    view.addConstrainsWithFormat(format: "H:|-20-[v0]-20-[v1]", views: labelArray[0], labelArray[1])
    view.addConstrainsWithFormat(format: "V:|-20-[v0]", views: labelArray[0])
    view.addConstrainsWithFormat(format: "V:|-20-[v0]", views: labelArray[1])
```

the problem is, the first object in the array appears but the rest don't. Is there a reason for this, or have i done something wrong in my code? I don't have to use an array to make this work obviously, but I was just curious as to what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change `var labelArray = [UILabel()]` to `var labelArray = [UILabel]()` and it will work fine.

You inserted your first label here `var labelArray = [UILabel()]`, so the second label was not in position 1 of your array but in position 2, because your array have 3 labels. The correct way to create empty array is `var labelArray = [UILabel]()`.